# Como fazer os dois primeiros números de uma sequência Math.random não sejam IGUAIS

Tags: javascript, array, while

Fiz um sistema de loteria a fim de aprendizado, não vou postar o código inteiro aqui só a parte que estou empacado.

É o seguinte: O sorteio do PC é uma sequencia de 6 números que apresento no DOM (isso n importa), dai quero que os dois primeiros números NUNCA sejam iguais.

Eu tentei isso com While mas não está dando certo, vejam:

```
    //gera o sorteio de 6 numeros de 1 a 20
    var rn1 = 1 + (Math.round(Math.random() * 19));
    var rn2 = 1 + (Math.round(Math.random() * 19));
    var rn3 = 1 + (Math.round(Math.random() * 19));
    var rn4 = 1 + (Math.round(Math.random() * 19));
    var rn5 = 1 + (Math.round(Math.random() * 19));
    var rn6 = 1 + (Math.round(Math.random() * 19));

    //eis oq eu tentei
    if(rn2 == rn1){ // se rn1 = rn2
        while(rn2 == rn1){ // comece o loop
            gerarnew1 = 1 + (Math.round(Math.random() * 19)); // gera um novo valor de 1 a 20 e roda até que...
                if(gerarnew1 != rn1){ // ...não seja mais = rn1
                    rn2 = gerarnew1; // entao atribuo esse novo numero a rn2
                    break; // paro o loop e, pela logica rn2 agora é != rn1
                }
        }
    }
    //entao sao armazenados aqui e apresentados dps no resto do codigo
    var rsorteio = new Array(rn1,rn2,rn3,rn4,rn5,rn6);
```

Mas como estou postando aqui certamente é porque não deu certo, eu rodo o algoritmo várias vezes e uma hora ele aparece com os dois primeiros números iguais.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Sugerem que eu poste o código inteiro?

Comment: Cara, muito estranho. Consegue criar um jsfiddle? Outra coisa, você pode simplificar seu código que checa repetições para `while (rn1 === rn2) { rn2 = 1 + (Math.round(Math.random() * 19)); }`

Comment: Dá para aceitar alguma das respostas?

Answer (score 12):

Segue uma solução usando o embaralhamento de Fisher-Yates.

Esse algoritmo tem a característica de não repetir os dados, pois ele simplesmente troca a posição dos membros.

O algoritmo é um loop bem simples, ele inicia do primeiro ítem, e troca com algum dos seguintes aleatoriamente (até com "ele mesmo") e pode ser considerado "embaralhado" já. Isto é feito com o ítem seguinte, sorteando dele mesmo até o último (não mexe mais com o primeiro, só dali em diante). O mesmo é feito com o terceiro ítem (não mexe mais com os dois anteriores) e assim sucessivamente.

Segue o código:

```js
var max = 20;
var set = [];
var i, j, t;
for( var i = 1; i <= max; i++ ) set.push( i );

for( i = 1; i < ( max - 1 ); i++ ) {
  j = i + ( Math.round( Math.random() * ( max - i - 1 ) ) );
  t = set[j];
  set[j] = set[i - 1];
  set[i - 1] = t;
}


// Demonstrando o resultado pegando 6 números
for( i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) document.body.innerHTML += set[i]+'<br>';
document.body.innerHTML += 'Clique novamente em "executar" para outro sorteio';
```

Versão moderna (1964 :P) do algoritmo:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm

Comment: Você deu a resposta que eu vim aqui para dar. O problema é que neste caso tudo bem, supõe-se que o array não será grande, mas quando o range dos números for imenso isso pode ser um problema de memória (armazenar num array, embaralhar e tirar o primeiro elemento)

Comment: Bacco, então, era pra n repetir nenhum sim, mas eu queria uma resposta pra n repetir os 2 primeiros, de forma q com o resto eu me virasse pela logica.

Em fim, o que tu achou dessa gambiarra q eu fiz? jsfiddle.net/r3r3ra9a

Tá funcionando perfeitamente ao menos. O ruim é que se passar de 6 numeros fica giga, sou iniciante e tals.

Comment: Aprimorei mas ainda tá 1a merd http://jsfiddle.net/fh0jf07s/

Comment: @renatoargh tomei por base uma loteria, em que pode haver o bolão, com vários números, e mais importante que isso, na homogeneidade aleatória (que Fisher-Yates dá), mas se for um caso em que você quer poucos aleatórios de uma coleção gigantesca, concordo que haja métodos mais econômicos.

Answer (score 7):

Aqui fica uma sugestão mais DRY. Ou seja sem repetir código.

```
var numeros = [];

function novoNumero(index) {
    var sugestao = 1 + (Math.round(Math.random() * 19));
    if (index == 1 && sugestao == numeros[0]) sugestao = novoNumero(index);
    return sugestao;
}
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var numero = novoNumero(i);
    numeros.push(numero);
}

console.log(numeros.join(' - '));
// dá por exemplo: 16 - 12 - 17 - 2 - 19 - 19
```

Aqui fica um teste correndo esse código **10.000** vezes.
Dê olhada na consola: http://jsfiddle.net/6vvyh0a3/

Nesse código que coloquei a função `novoNumero` aceita como parametro o index, ou seja a posição do numero na array. O ciclo `for` vai de 0 a 5 e a cada iteração chama a função.

A função cria um numero novo e, caso o valor que a variável `index` recebeu seja `1`, então compara com o primeiro numero já gerado na iteração anterior (ie `numeros[0]`). Caso eles sejam iguais, a função chama-se a sí própria e gera um novo numero que irá novamente comparar.

Depois disso, seguro de não ter numeros repetidos, faz o push (insere) esse numero na array.

Comment: Sério, o que tu achou disso q eu fiz? http://jsfiddle.net/r3r3ra9a/

Tá bem gambiarra, mas tá funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: Aprimorei 1 pouco, mas ainda ta 1a merd http://jsfiddle.net/fh0jf07s/

Comment: @ropbla9 eu não gosto de ver código repetido. Têm de usar funções. Não serve a solução que está na minha resposta?

Comment: serviu sim, perfeitamente mas eu fiz o meu proprio para exercitar.

Comment: Daria para voce explicar melhor seu codigo?

Comment: @ropbla9 claro. Editei a pergunta e expliquei melhor. Diga se algo está pouco claro.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que a forma mais adequada para esse problema (não repetir elementos) é utilizar o [tipo set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) do javascript pois ele não permite elementos duplicados. Isso simplifica a tanto a geração dos números como o controle/fim do loop para gerar a cartela e o jogo.

Basicamente seria algo como:

```
var cartela = new Set();
while(cartela.size < 6) cartela.add(número aleatório)
```

Separei o código em três funções uma que gera a cartela, outra para o soterio e uma que contabiliza os acertos.

```
function gerarSorteio(){
    var sorteio = new Set();  
    while(sorteio.size < 6){
        sorteio.add(Math.round(Math.random() * 20));
    }
    return sorteio;
}

function marcarDezenas(){
    var cartela = new Set();
    while(cartela.size < 6){
        cartela.add(parseInt(prompt("Informe a Dezena:")));
    }
    return cartela;
}

function resultado(sorteio, cartela){
    var acertos = [];
    for (let item of sorteio){
        if(cartela.has(item)){
            acertos.push(item);
        }
    }
    return acertos;
}

var sorteio = gerarSorteio();
var cartela = marcarDezenas();
var acertos = resultado(sorteio, cartela);

console.log(sorteio);
console.log(cartela);
console.log(acertos);
```

**[Exemplo - replit](https://repl.it/repls/AshamedDrabGraywolf)**