# A função de embaralhamento tem armadilhas não facilmente percebidas?

Tags: javascript, funções

A função `shuffle` recebe como entrada uma *array* e a embaralha.

```js
// 
function shuffle(a) {
 // atribui a variável n a quantidades de elementos da array a.
 n = a.length;
 // Percorre a array a da posição 0 até a ultima posição.
 for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 //Sorteia uma posição aleatória entre i e n−1 e atribui para a variável swap
 swap = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * (n - i - 1));
 // Troca os valores das posições i e swap da array a.
 var aux = a[i];
 a[i] = a[swap];
 a[swap] = aux;
 }
}
var array = [5, 3, 1, 4, 2];
if (shuffle(array)) console.log(array);
```

Existem potenciais armadilhas (*pitfalls*) na função acima? Se SIM qual é ou quais são? Comente a resposta.

Mandei executar e não deu resultado.

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida em resposta ao exercício?

Comment: tentei executar e não consegui e não entendi o funcionamento da função

Comment: O seu if está impedindo de mostrar a saída. Tire o if e execute a função direto. Aí sim tente entender como funciona e quais podem ser as potenciais armadilhas.

Comment: @AlbertoVerzemiassiBorguesani A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

De forma geral não, em específico não podemos dizer porque não sabemos o que deseja, se ela resolve o que precisa.  Este algoritmo tem até nome, chama-se Fisher-Yates, e é o mais usado para embaralhar dados. Como ser visto em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34941/101) (uma mais completa que leva à análise de alternativas).

A única coisa ruim na função é que ela não declara as variáveis localmente com [`var` ou `let`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/101) (uma dela sim, então o código é estranho por estar inconsistente), não declarando assim [a variável fica global e aí sim terá armadilhas complicadas de resolver](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171327/101). Se executar só isso não tem problema, se tiver outras partes de código essas variáveis podem se confundir com outras, pode até não dar problema aí mas criará problema nas outras partes, dependendo de como forem escritas.

A função em si está correta, a chamada dela está bem errada e não faz sentido. O `if` não tem função alguma aí e estám andando imprimir um objeto e não os elmentos do *array* que parece que é o que deseja.

```js
function shuffle(a) {
    let n = a.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        let swap = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * (n - i - 1));
        let aux = a[i];
        a[i] = a[swap];
        a[swap] = aux;
    }
}

let array = [5, 3, 1, 4, 2];
shuffle(array);
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) console.log(array[i]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/FisherYates.js).